# UIActivityViewController: Choosing an activity for which permissions are denied leads to a dead end

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `UIActivityViewController` to implement image sharing.

```
UIActivityViewController *shareVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image] applicationActivities:nil];
[shareVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
    NSLog(@"completed image export activity: %@ - %d", activityType, completed);
}];
[self presentViewController:shareVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

In testing, I have noticed that if the user selects, for example, "Assign to Contact", but then denies the permission in the ensuing dialog, then they are taken to a screen that says "**This app does not have access to your contacts.** You can enable access in Privacy Settings.", from which there is no way to back out. The only way for them then to get back to the actual app is to manually restart it.

I'm fairly happy to leave this behaviour as is for now since I don't anticipate any users will be particularly bothered by it, but I'd like to know if there is a sensible way to work around it, and if it is indeed the expected behaviour.

Comment: I haven't tried it on the simulator :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the iPad platform, and in that context presenting a `UIActivityViewController` directly is wrong according to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which states that

> When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

In most ways, the behaviour of the modally presented view controller on iPad seemed perfectly fine, but this case illustrates why it is not appropriate. I don't know how the equivalent case is handled on iPhone / iPod touch as I haven't really looked at those platforms just yet.

Now that I am presenting it in a `UIPopoverController`, the view explaining that the app doesn't have access to contacts appears within the popup, and is dismissed as the popup is dismissed. Unfortunately it appears that the completion handler is not called in this case; I'm not sure if that's an iOS bug or if I lack understanding of something. It is a slight problem for me at the moment, so I'll have to work around it.

Unfortunately, it seems relatively unlikely that anyone experiencing a related problem will be helped by my question / answer; maybe I'll try to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe you could check if a segue is called when the new "This app does not have access to your contacts. You can..."-Viewcontroller is shown. Then you could manipulate the destinationViewController property of the segue and add for example a button, with an action enabling the user to go back.

All highly theroretical.

Comment: Sounds like a potential avenue to explore... I have more pressing issues for now but at least that's a lead.

Comment: Wouldn't such a segue have to be within your app? The access denied message comes from iOS itself.